PowerBI Report Builder: Sparklines - 'Align Axes In' option is missing from the Axes options
I'm using a sparkline column chart and the columns are autosizing where I have missing data, instead of showing all 6 categories and leaving a space where the zero value should be (see image).

The documentation for PowerBI Report Builder states the following
Align the data in a sparkline or data bar

Add a sparkline or data bar to a table or matrix.
Select the sparkline or data bar, and then select Horizontal Axis Properties or Vertical Axis Properties.
On the Axis Options tab, check the Align axes in box, and then in the dropdown box, select the group on which to align the axis.

In my version of PBI Report Builder (15.7.1807.730) the Align Axes In option isn't available or has been moved somewhere else, which I'm unable to locate.
Any help on how to get all categories to show in the sparkline would be greatly appreciated.

Found it, the setting is located in the Series Group Properties, setting Synchronize Groups In will accomplish the task

